# pytest: ignore third party library warnings with -Werror

Tags: python, pytest

I am running my unit tests as:

```bash
pytest -Werror
```

... to ensure my code does not raise any warnings.

However I am using third party libraries I cannot fix. These third party libraries are causing warnings which then will cause `pytest -Werror` to abort.

In my case the warning is `DeprecationWarning` so I cannot disable this warning by the exception class, as it is too wide and affects other code too.

How do I suppress the third party library warnings so that pytest ignores them?

I have tried:

```py
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        call_third_party_code_with_warnings()
```

... but `pytest` still terminates the test as `ERROR` and ignores `warnings.catch_warnings`.

Specifically warning is

```
  File "/Users/moo/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/trade-executor-8Oz1GdY1-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 196, in __init_subclass__
    warnings.warn(
DeprecationWarning: Subclassing validator classes is not intended to be part of their public API. A future version will make doing so an error, as the behavior of subclasses isn't guaranteed to stay the same between releases of jsonschema. Instead, prefer composition of validators, wrapping them in an object owned entirely by the downstream library.
```

Disabling warning output in `pyproject.toml` seems to disable the warning output in pytest, but does not seem to affect `-Werror` flag exceptions.

```ini
filterwarnings = [
    "ignore:::.*.jsonschema",
    # DeprecationWarning: Subclassing validator classes is not intended to be part of their public API. A future version will make doing so an error, as the behavior of subclasses isn't guaranteed to stay the same between releases of jsonschema. Instead, prefer composition of validators, wrapping them in an object owned entirely by the downstream library.
    "ignore:::.*.validators",
    "ignore::DeprecationWarning:openapi_spec_validator.*:"
]
```

Comment: As another perspective: An argument against "-Werror" (although in case of C/C++) is made [here](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/05/22/werror-is-not-your-friend/): The gist is that new versions of (in your case) `python` / `pytest` may introduce new warnings causing build / test problems (even apart from third party library code).

Answer (score 3):

You can add `filterwarnings` in `pytest.ini`

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings = ignore::DeprecationWarning:THIRD_PARTY_NAME.*:
```

or ignore everything from this library if you prefer

```
filterwarnings = ignore:::.*.THIRD_PARTY_NAME
```

Edit

Instead of using `-Werror` flag you can use `pytest.ini` to get the same results and ignore the library

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings = 
    error
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

I know you don't want to silence completely this warning, how ever it's not raised from the third-party, it's raised from `builtins.py`.

You could try something like `ignore::jsonschema.validators.DeprecationWarning`, but I doubt it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much Guy. This answer does not seem to be help, as it looks like `filterwarnings` only affects pytest output, but not `-Werror` exceptions. I will edit the question for clarifications.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Edited my answer. Not exactly what you are looking for, but might point you in the right direction.